# Make (install from source) python without running tests

Tags: python, linux, makefile, build

I compiling python from source tar. All works good, but tests running 2 hours and two times. How to bypass these tests?

```
0:16:20 [178/405] test_inspect
0:16:26 [179/405] test_int
0:16:27 [180/405] test_int_literal
0:16:27 [181/405] test_io
0:18:18 [182/405] test_ioctl -- test_io passed in 1 min 51 sec
0:18:19 [183/405] test_ipaddress
0:18:22 [184/405] test_isinstance
0:18:23 [185/405] test_iter
0:18:24 [186/405] test_iterlen
0:18:25 [187/405] test_itertools
0:19:09 [188/405] test_json -- test_itertools passed in 44 sec
0:19:30 [189/405] test_keyword
```

As result

```
make 7724,86s user 188,63s system 101% cpu 2:10:18,93 total
```

I make its distribution like this

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 3.6.1
PYTHON_URL = https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz

wget -O dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz ${PYTHON_URL}

cd dl 
tar xf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tar.xz

mkdir -p dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}-build/
cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} 
    ./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$$(pwd)-build --cache-file=$$(pwd)/cache-file
```

This commands runs tests twice:

```
make -C dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -j8 
make -C dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -j8 install
```

p.s. This is part of another make file.

Comment: What is your tarball ?

Comment: How did you build? With `make`?

Comment: @Coldspeed updated

Comment: @glegoux 3.6 from python.org

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The configure option `--enable-optimizations` enables running test suites to generate data for profiling Python. The resulting python binary has better performance in executing python code. Improvements noted [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue24915)

```
From configure help:
--enable-optimizations  Enable expensive optimizations (PGO, etc). Disabled by default.
```

From wikipedia

```
 profile-guided optimisation uses the results of profiling test runs of the instrumented program to optimize the final generated code.
```

In short, you should not skip tests when using `--enable-optimizations` as the data required for profiling is generated by running tests.
You can run `make -j8 build_all` followed by `make -j8 install` to skip tests once(the tests would still run with `install` target), but that would defeat the purpose.
You can instead drop the configure flag for better build times.

Comment: I am afraid there's no way out in that case. If you're not going to build python often, go with optimizations.

Comment: Is it normal to optimizations to run for hours? I tried to install 3.9.7 on a oracle linux 6 and the tests run for more than 5 hours then I canceled it. Will the build fail if I "cntrl+c" while in the test phase?

Answer (score 18):

just build and install with

```
make -j8 build_all
make -j8 altinstall
```

Comment: This used to work, but starting Python 3.11 is not the case anymore, tests are executed anyway

Answer (score 10):

I did some (quick) research on skipping the test runs when building *Python* by instructing either:

- *configure* - passing some args (e.g. `--without-tests`, `--disable-tests`, `--skip-tests`)
- *make* - specifying some variable (either via *env* *var*s or *cmdline*)

The former yielded no results. The latter (by looking in the *Makefile* template) revealed the fact that test execution is invoked by calling *${PYTHON_SRC_DIR}/Tools/scripts/run_tests.py* (which sets some stuff and calls another script, which calls another one, ...). 
Note that I found the file on *Python 3.5(.4)* and *Python 3.6(.4)* but **not** on *Python 2.7(.14)*. A little bit more research revealed that it is possible to skip the (above) test run. What you need to do is:

```bash
make -C dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -j8 EXTRATESTOPTS=--list-tests install
```

**Notes**:

- *Google*ing didn't reveal anything (relevant) on *EXTRATESTOPTS*, so I guess it's **not officialy supported**
- You could also set `EXTRATESTOPTS=--list-tests` as an environment variable, before launching (inner) *make*
- Needless to say that if some "minor" error happened during build (e.g. a non critical external module (like *_ssl.so* for example) failed to build), there will be no tests to fail, so you'll only find about it at runtime (which would be terribly nasty if it would happen in production)

***@EDIT0***:

After @amohr 's comment, I decided to play a little bit more, so I ran the whole process:

1. *configure* (opts)
2. *make* (opts)
3. `make install`

on a *Lnx* (*Ubtu 16*) machine with 2 *CPU*s, where one (full) test run takes ~24 minutes. Here are my findings (*Python 3.6*):

- It **ran successfully** on *Python 3.5(.4)*
- The solution that I suggested earlier, operates at the 3<sup>rd</sup> step, so it only skips **the 2<sup>nd</sup> test run**: it operates on the (root) *Makefile*'s ***test*** target (`make test`) which is invoked by *install* target
- Regarding the 1<sup>st</sup> test run, by checking the *Makefile*, and *make*'s output, here's what I discovered that happens at the 2<sup>nd</sup> (*make*) step:

  1. The *C* sources are built "normally"
  2. Tests are being run (I deducted that some profile data is stored somewhere)
  3. The *C* sources are rebuilt with different flags (e.g. in my case *gcc*'s `-fprofile-generate` was replaced by `-fprofile-use -fprofile-correction` (check [[GNU.GCC]: Options That Control Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for more details)) to make use of the profile info generated at previous (sub) step
- Skipping the 1<sup>st</sup> test run would automatically imply **no optimizations**. Way(s) of achieving:

  1. `make build_all` (at 2<sup>nd</sup> step) - as suggested by other answers

     - Here's a snippet of the (root) *Makefile* generated by *configure* (**with** `--enable-optimizations`):

       ```bash
       all:            profile-opt
       build_all:      check-clean-src $(BUILDPYTHON) oldsharedmods sharedmods gdbhooks \
                       Programs/_testembed python-config
       ```
     - And here's one **without** it:

       ```bash
       all:            build_all
       build_all:      check-clean-src $(BUILDPYTHON) oldsharedmods sharedmods gdbhooks \
                       Programs/_testembed python-config
       ```
     - As seen, running:

       1. `configure --enable-optimizations`
       2. `make build_all`

       is identical to:

       1. `configure`
       2. `make`
  2. Manually modifying the (root) *Makefile* between 1<sup>st</sup> (`configure --enable-optimizations`) and 2<sup>nd</sup> (*make*) steps:

     - Find the macro definition `PROFILE_TASK=-m test.regrtest --pgo` (for me it was around line *~250*)
     - Add `--list-tests` at the end
     - Substeps (*#2.*)***#1.*** and (*#2.*)***#3.*** are exactly the same, while for (*#2.*)***#2.***, the tests are not being run. That can mean that either:

       - The 2<sup>nd</sup> sources build is identical to the 1<sup>st</sup> one (which would make it completely useless)
       - The 2<sup>nd</sup> does some optimizations (without having any information), which means that it could crash at runtime (I think / hope it's the former case)

Comment: I can confirm that `EXTRATESTOPTS=--list-tests` during installation does the trick on Linux.

Comment: note this does not work for 3.5.x as you'll get: "regrtest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --list-tests"

Answer (score 7):

the default build target for optimized builds includes running the tests.
to skip them, try:

```
 make -C dl/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} -j8 build_all
```

Comment: `make build_all` appears to be a correct answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same problem with python 3.7.6 and based on reverse engineering the Makefile, found that following steps will build python quickly while running the tests too (so that we don't loose on --enable-optimization flag)

```
cd /home/ubuntu
PYTHON_VER=3.7.6
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VER/Python-$PYTHON_VER.tgz
tar xvf Python-$PYTHON_VER.tgz
cd Python-$PYTHON_VER/
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations
make profile-gen-stamp; ./python -m test.regrtest --pgo -j8; make build_all_merge_profile; touch profile-run-stamp; make
make install
```

The key is run python tests in parallel by passing -j8 to it.

Answer (score 0):

the first part of tests is required for optimizing the code. simply you can't / should not skip it.