# Building Python 3 without running unit tests

Tags: python, dreamhost

In trying to install a custom Python 3 environment on my webhost (Dreamhost), `make` fails because the webhost's process monitor sees the unit tests as taking too much CPU. While I am able to install the untested Python binaries with `make install` anyway, I would love to be able to do the build without it even trying to run the unit tests in the first place (mostly to avoid getting the "helpful" automated email from Dreamhost that suggests I upgrade to a VPS).

Since I'm only building stable releases of Python it's pretty much guaranteed that the unit tests would all pass anyway. So, is there an option to python's `./configure` or `make` that will cause it to skip attempting to run the test suite?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708262/make-install-from-source-python-without-running-tests

Comment: @Cplusplusplus Thanks, I swear I searched far and wide but couldn't find anything about this... Although it seems the answers on that are basically, "You can't."

Comment: Oh wait, I see that @umläute's answer has the correct magic - `make build_all`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make (install from source) python without running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708262/make-install-from-source-python-without-running-tests)